# Use of "Taken care of" as a reponse

Tags: phrase-usage, vocabulary

Dialogue:

> — Did you do your homework?
>   — Taken care of.

Is this a normal response or rarely used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't describe it as "normal" *or* "rare". I'd call it "niche", or possibly "trendy".

The "normal" response might be:

> Yes, I took care of my homework.

However, more "terse" responses might include:

- Check.
- Done.
- Finished.
- Taken care of.

Words and phrases like this often crop up, rise in popularity, and then temper off. They often become popular among a younger demographic first. (In recent years, I've been introduced to some new and "epic" words and phrases from my kids and their friends.)

I can't remember anyone ever saying "Taken care of" when I've asked if they've completed a task (hence, I'm hesitant to call it "normal"). Yet it's not so foreign that I couldn't figure out what it meant (therefore, I wouldn't want to call it "rare," either).

A more verbose (yet equally slangy) response might include:

- I've crossed that off my to-do list.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a normal use. "Taken care of" can often be given as a reply to the status of a routine task like homework.

Answer (score 0):

Not to be contrary, but I don't use it as a normal response. I do, however,use such a phrase when I am in my mothering or teacher-modes...and I am both.

To me, the into,iced message is one of suggesting responsibility for a task. Otherwise, a simple, "did you... ?" should suffice.